# Count positive observations in dataframe using R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with over 4000 columns and 3790 rows. Column represent companies and row present daily observation data for them. 3790 rows imply 15 years of daily observations. Now I want to calculate that each column has equal to or more than 100 daily observation  plus positive it to be positive value over the 15 year sample i.e. from Jan-2000 to Dec-2014. In short, I want to filter out companies out from my sample that have less than 100 positive observations out from 3790.
The structure of my data is such it has missing values because companies listed at various point of times. For instance, company listed in year 2003,hence, all NAs before 2003.
I illustrate the structure of my dataframe as follows:

```
Date         A       B      C
30/12/1999  79.5    325     NA
04/01/2000  79.5    325     NA
05/01/2000  79.5    322.5   NA
06/01/2000  79.5    327.5   NA
07/01/2000  79.5    327.5   NA
10/01/2000  79.5    327.5   NA
11/01/2000  79.5    327.5   NA
12/01/2000  79.5    331.5   NA
13/01/2000  79.5    334     NA
14/01/2000  79.5    334     NA
17/01/2000  94.5    350     NA
18/01/2000  95.5    351.5   NA
19/01/2000  94.5    352.5   NA
20/01/2000  97.5    352.5   NA
21/01/2000  97.5    352.5   NA
24/01/2000  97.5    352.5   NA
25/01/2000  97.5    352.5   NA
```

I would appreciate your help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x>0 & !is.na(x)) > 100, df1)
```